# Print preview splits characters between 2 pages in Google Chrome version 53.0.2785.143

Tags: google-chrome, printing

Please refer the following image :
[image]

Is it a bug of Google Chrome or any adjustment I need to do ? please help me regarding it.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the print preview. Does this also happen in the actual output (PDF or paper)?

Comment: I tried to save as PDF and its happening.

Comment: Chrome 88 is still splitting characters across pages. Opera is bad too. Firefox might be good, or it's a coincidence of alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all for answers.

Finally I got the answer from the following :
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1524#issuecomment-85072480

I need to do CSS adjustments as follows :

```
table tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

That's it my problem is solved.

Comment: Jesus Christ, you saved me!!! That was driving me crazy. Firefox was actually printing correctly whereas Chrome didn't!!